# Direct product for minimal normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, direct-product

Given a finite group $G$, $N$ is a minimal normal subgroup and $S_i$ are simple subgroups of $G$ for $i=1, \cdots , r$.

Next, the problem said "suppose $N = S_1\times \cdots \times S_r$"

First does this notation always mean the **internal direct product** in group theory? Since it has strong implications such as

1. each $S_i$ are normal in $N$
2. $S_i \cap S_j = id$ for $i\neq j$
3. $S_i$ and $S_j$ commute for $i\neq j$.

Second, the problem asked to show that for each $g\in G$, $gS_1g^{-1} = S_i$ for some $i$.

The solution just said it is true because the minimal normal subgroup of $N$ are of the form $id \times \cdots \times S_i \times \cdots id$, why does this imply the result?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes it means the internal direct product. The fact that the $S_i$ are minimal normal subgroups follows from the fact that they are simple. Then $gS_1g^{-1}$ is also a minimal normal subgroup. So you have to prove that the $S_i$ are the only minimal normal subgroups. You should try and do that yourself.

Comment: Presumably you also assume the $S_i$ are non-abelian? Otherwise you could have $N=(\mathbb{F}_p)^r$ for some prime $p$ and $G=N\rtimes GL_r(p)$ and the second problem is not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the comments, we assume $S_i$'s are non-abelian simple groups.

Next we will show that the $S_i$ are the only minimal normal subgroups of $N$. Suppose there is some other minimal normal subgroup $H$, then we have 
$[S_i : H]$ is a normal subgroup of $S_i$, to see this, let $c\in [S_i, H]$ then we know because $H$ is normal $c\in H$, for each $s\in S_i$, we have 
$$scs^{-1}c^{-1} \in [S_i, H]$$
and by clousure of group multiplication, 
$$scs^{-1}c^{-1}c \in  [S_i, H].$$

Furthermore because $S_i$'s are simple,  so $[S_i, H]$ must be $1$. 
This implies $H$ commutes with all $S_i$'s thus $H \subset Z(N)$. But since $Z(S_i) = 1$, we see that $Z(N) = 1 =  H$.

So the only minimal normal subgroups of $N$ are $S_i$'s. 
And finally $g\in G$, conjugation of $g\in G$ defines a group isomorphism from $N$ to $N$. Thus $S_i$ will be mapped to some minimal simple group $S_j$ for some $j$.